# Job Offer with Company A While Having Interviews and Potential Interviews Lined Up

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-search, job-offer, ethics

I'll be completing my degree soon. However, my husband got a job several hours away from where I was attending school, so I am completing my coursework at a different school and transferring them back. This means I'll be done with classes this December, but won't have my degree until May. For my industry, some full time positions require a degree, while some do not.

Therefore, I've started my job search by going to the school's career fair. There, I found a paid internship position with Company A. They immediately called me back for an interview. I went into the interview Monday, and that afternoon they called me back and asked if I was still interested and what day I could start. I told them that I was still interested (because I am), but I asked for sometime to check my schedule before answering when I could start.

The position is part-time only - I could work a max of 30 hours in the spring, but, I could work and be paid as it doesn't require a degree. Plus, I could start working immidetaly (as I am not working this semester) and have a little extra income coming in now. But, the position is internship only: they don't have enough full-time positions to higher the interns on full-time. So, it's a high turn over, and they know it, and they would expect me to leave come May (although, they wouldn't force me out.) So, it's a great back up job, but I will be at some point needing a full-time position.

Thing is, I have an interview on Friday with Company B that will be offering a full-time position. But, a) don't know if I'll get it, and b) still undecided if it's what I want. Company B is a great company, but I'm just being nervous about how well I could actually do the work. Plus, I think this company might require me to have a degree, so couldn't start there until May (but, I'm not sure. I talked with a lot of companies, and each one said different things.)

Then, there was Company C. I really liked the position being offered, but they haven't set an interview up yet. They will be doing on-campus interviews in the next few weeks, and I've already been told I will be invited when they figure out the dates for the interviews. I believe this one might let me start work in January, but the lady had to talk to HR to verify it.

And, likewise, there were several companies I talked to, but, as they are looking for employees for Spring or Summer, they haven't started the interview processes yet. It's a complete unknown whether or not I'll get an offer from any of the companies, but I was planning on trying to apply to the positions online to give myself a better chance.

So, the question becomes, what do I do with Company A? I had a lot of fun during the interview - the most fun I've ever had in an interview. I know that I would fit in well with the team, and I got really excited about working there. But, it's not the sort of position that will turn into long-term employment, so my fear is, if I accept them position, will I be locking myself out of a better opportunity? But, if I decline the position, and I don't get another job offer (or at least can't start working until May), am I shooting myself in the foot?

What I would really love to do is accept the position, then continue the job hunt. If I find something better that starts in January, then go for it. But, I feel this would be dishonest. Of course, if the position I found starts in May, after I have my degree, then no problem.

On a side note: Company A did say there should be some positions come open for the Spring if I feel that works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

Whew, quite the conundrum. There are a few points to consider here.

### Internships are not always considered "Job/Career Experience" when hunting for a full-time job

Several companies that I have worked with in the past don't exactly advertise their policy on internship experience, but the hiring policy instructs HR (and in some cases, HR resume filtering software) to ignore internship related experience unless the internship was with **that company**. That's not to say that any of the companies that you'll be looking into have that policy, but it's something to consider.

### Reality VS Expectations

The fact is, you have a solid offer for **something**, which is a good start. You obviously interview well and were able to grab the attention of a company in your career field, which is great. Also, an internship might be a good way for you to explore jobs in your career field without committing to something too serious right from the start. This gives you an opportunity to make sure you are in the field you want to be in, and solidify what you want out of the first years of your career.

That being said, you don't have anything solid from the other companies that you're interested in. Even if you did, you don't sound too sure about it anyway. Just make sure that you have a clear understanding of a *solid offer* as opposed to a *potential offer*.

### You Don't Owe Anybody *Anything*

Now, I know that sounds harsh and ungrateful. But the fact is, business is business. If you accept this internship, get a few weeks deep into it, and a better offer comes along where you think you might have more success and gain more experience/resume padding.....go for it! That's not to say that you should be ruthless with how you go about switching jobs, companies, careers, etc. But the reality is, this is **your** career, and you have to do what is best for you. As you already said, the internship company is already expecting a high turnover rate.

My personal opinion would be, take the internship and see if something else develops. Then, you at least have **something**. If a better opportunity presents itself, don't be afraid to do what is best for your situation. Remember, no matter how much it may seem that a company is "doing you a favor" by employing you, that is **never** the case. Employment is a give-take relationship. Be at work on time, give 100% while you're there, and that's your only obligation.

I wish you the best of luck. If you have any more questions, feel free to let me know.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No to mention that most company won't hold it against you if you quit an internship because you got a full time position somewhere else as long as you give them enough notice. If they do not want to lose you, they might even make  you a counter offer, which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

B and C haven't made any offer to you. The only thing you really have is the offer from A. All the rest is vaporware i.e. expectations and hopes that may or may not pan out.

I'd say, take the position at A and build your resume and skills set (and your self-confidence) there and bring in some money until you get an offer from either B or C. At which point, you will have to decide. In the meantime, take it one day at a time and scratch one itch at a time. You'll decide at the time you'll get the offers, where the offers specify the pre-requisites that you must meet.

If you get an offer from B, your built-in reason for leaving A is your need for a full-time position that gets you launched into a career - a perfectly legitimate reason for leaving, by the way. Ditto for C. At any rate, let's not count the chickens before they hatch - you still have to get the offers from B and C.